# How do you write an input layer with Tensorflow's Functional API that expects a Dataset object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, functional-api

I am trying to create an Input Layer using `tf.keras.Input` using the type_spec argument to specify an input of DatasetSpec using Tensorflow's Functional API so that I can iterate over it later. If I try to define an input layer by specifying shape, I get error messages complaining that iterating over tf.tensor is not allowed.

```
X = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,75))
Y = np.random.uniform(size=(1000))

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
data = data.batch(batch_size=100, drop_remainder=True)


input = tf.keras.Input(type_spec = tf.data.DatasetSpec.from_value(data))
```

I got the following error:
`ValueError: KerasTensor only supports TypeSpecs that have a shape field; got DatasetSpec, which does not have a shape.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` object (output of `tf.data`) is the tuple of two item (`X` and `Y`). In order to create specification layer (`keras.Input`) with `tf.data.DatasetSpec.from_value(data)`, you need to get the shape of first element.

```
tf.data.DatasetSpec.from_value(data)

DatasetSpec((TensorSpec(shape=(100, 75), dtype=tf.float64, name=None),
TensorSpec(shape=(100,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)), TensorShape([]))
```

Here is a dummy model with your approach,

```
# element_spec[0] <- shape of the first element.
input = tf.keras.Input(
    type_spec = tf.data.DatasetSpec.from_value(data).element_spec[0]
)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(input)
model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
model.compile(loss='mse')

model.fit(data, epochs=3)
Epoch 1/3
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2506
Epoch 2/3
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2441
Epoch 3/3
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2378
```